# text label svg, long text in other line

Tags: css, svg

I have a long text. It text will be dynamic, can be short o long. How can I make the text stay in another line by exceeding the width of the text tag that contains it? I also want to know how to apply border style to the rect label.

thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/yftfy15q/

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

var groupTooltip = svg.append("g")

var rect = groupTooltip.append('rect')
  .attr('width', 300)
  .attr('height', 100)
  .style('fill', 'white')
  .attr('class','myclass')
  .attr('stroke', 'black');


var text = groupTooltip.append('text').text('This is some information XDDDDDDDDDSSSSSSSSS XDDDD XDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD')
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('x', 120)
  .attr('y', 30)
  .attr('id', 'tooltip_text')

var image = groupTooltip.append('image')
  .attr("x", 4)
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('height', 100)
  .attr('id', 'tooltip_image')
  .attr('xlink:href', 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split text to certain limit and then append it inside `tspan`.
Here i limit text to `18` and append each inside `tspan`,positioned each accordingly.

```
var texts="This is some information XDDDDDDDDDSSSSSSSSS XDDDD XDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD";
var list=[];
list=texts.match(/.{1,18}/g);
var text = groupTooltip.append('text')
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('x', 120)
  .attr('y', 30)
  .attr('id', 'tooltip_text')
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  groupTooltip.select("text").append("tspan")
    .text(list[i])
    .attr("dy", i ? "1.2em" : 0)
    .attr("x", 110)
    .attr("text-anchor", "left")
    .attr("class", "tspan" + i);
}
```

> The `text` element can be arranged in any number of sub-groups with the
>   `tspan` element. Each `tspan` element can contain different formatting and
>   position.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

var groupTooltip = svg.append("g")

var rect = groupTooltip.append('rect')
  .attr('width', 300)
  .attr('height', 100)
  .style('fill', 'white')
  .attr('class','myclass')
  .attr('stroke', 'black');

var texts="This is some information XDDDDDDDDDSSSSSSSSS XDDDD XDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD";
var list=[];
list=texts.match(/.{1,18}/g);
var text = groupTooltip.append('text')
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('x', 120)
  .attr('y', 30)
  .attr('id', 'tooltip_text')
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  groupTooltip.select("text").append("tspan")
    .text(list[i])
    .attr("dy", i ? "1.2em" : 0)
    .attr("x", 110)
    .attr("text-anchor", "left")
    .attr("class", "tspan" + i);
}

var image = groupTooltip.append('image')
  .attr("x", 4)
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('height', 100)
  .attr('id', 'tooltip_image')
  .attr('xlink:href', 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png')
```

```css
.myclass{
   stroke: blue;
   rx: 12;
   ry: 12;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks! but why the stlye of the rect is not aplied?

Comment: see my updated code above.you cannot apply border radius for rect,instead use `rx` and `ry` also color can be applyed through `stroke`